# Leaflet 1.7.1 popup on mobile Bug

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, openstreetmap

I am working on a new Leaflet map with **1.7.1**.
I noticed on my mobile device browsers (on Safari and Chrome) that the **popups are flickering** (not displaying/not showing up). I went on the Leaflet website with my mobile trying one of their example e.g. on **their very home-page** and I am facing the same problem. Is this my mobile or this problem is already known?

Comment: It is a known issue, see https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/7331 . This is the kind of question that you could answer yourself by perusing the project's issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

After more research ... I found out that this is an actual bug.
By commenting the following lines of code in the JS file will resolve the problem.

```
    // simulate click if the touch didn't move too much
            // if (this._isTapValid()) {
            //  this._simulateEvent('click', first);
            // }
```